# Why doesn't Clipboard.GetText work?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

```
String str = Clipboard.GetText();
```

throws an exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in PresentationCore.dll

How do I prevent this problem?

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: System.StackOverflowException ahh the namesake of this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text)
```

Or take a look here: 
[Clipboard.GetText returns null (empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-en/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at the accepted answer in this thread:

[Link to working code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)

In summary you need to ensure you start or are running in an `STAThread` with `staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`
I also suggest you add a little bit of sleep or wait after join as sometimes the clipboard content is not immediately available when `staThread.Join()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line above the `main()` method, your code will look like this:

```
[STAThread]

public static void main()
```

This solved the problem for me.