# Having trouble writing a simple VS2010 macro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

I'm trying to write a simple visual studio 2010 macro to search the solution for a string (gotten from the clipboard)

what I have so far:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule

    Sub TemporaryMacro()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FindinFiles")
        DTE.Find.FindWhat = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
        DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetFiles
        DTE.Find.MatchCase = True
        DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
        DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = True
        DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral
        DTE.Find.SearchPath = "Entire Solution"
        DTE.Find.SearchSubfolders = True
        DTE.Find.FilesOfType = ""
        DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResults2
        DTE.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionFindAll
        If (DTE.Find.Execute() = vsFindResult.vsFindResultNotFound) Then
            Throw New System.Exception("vsFindResultNotFound")
        End If
        DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindFindReplace).Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

unfortunately, it doens't work. When I try using it, I get a 'Value does not fall in expected range' error on the line 'DTE.Find.FindWhat = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()'. This is my first visual studio macro ever, so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and the problem is that `GetText()` is returning an empty string.  When you set `Find.FindWhat` with an empty string it throws the error.  For a test, try explicitly setting `Find.FindWhat` to a string literal like "hello" and see if the code still crashes (in my test it did not).

If not, then the question is why `GetTest()` returns an empty string.  After some poking around, I found another thread which discusses this same thing:

[Clipboard.GetText returns null (empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)

You might want to check that out (the solution is in C#).  For VB code, I found another thread that you might want to try:

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-general/10874/Clipboard-GetText-no-longer-working

Looks like an annoying bug to me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetText()` is failing because macros are not run in an STA thread.
That sounds weird but it is like this.
Therefore you have to wrap the `GetText()` so it is called inside of a STA thread.
Here is some code I use currently:

```
Private clipString As String = String.Empty

Function GetClipboardText() As String
    clipString = ""
    Dim data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    If Not data Is Nothing Then
        clipString = data.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.StringFormat)
    End If
    ' myString = DataObj.GetText(1)
    ' MsgBox(myString)

    ' clipString = _
    ' Clipboard.GetDataObject() _
    ' .GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.StringFormat)
End Function

Private Sub StoreClipBoardText(ByVal s As String)
    clipString = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.StringFormat)
End Sub
```

I think you have to do the same if you want to put something into the clipboard.