# Send clipboard content via email using Console Application c#

Tags: c#, email, console-application

I have managed to create simple app that will send e-mail with specific text, but I am wondering that is this possible to send the same e-mail, but with content of text being copied into clipboard?

In my `oMail.TextBody` I would like to paste content of clipboard and e-mail it.

```
    static void Main(string[] server)
    {
        SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
        EASendMail.SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();

        // Set sender email address
        oMail.From = "myEmail";

        // Set recipient email address
        oMail.To = "myEmail";

        // Set email subject
        oMail.Subject = "test email from c# project";

        // Set email body
        oMail.TextBody = "Clipboard content pasted here..."
     }
```

Is there any way to do it? Additionally I am `using EASendMail` namespace.

Comment: `Clipboard.GetText()`

Comment: @Pikoh
Thank you for your suggestion, but where should I use it. 
`oMail.TextBody = Clipboard.GetText();`

I did tried it, but it's sending an empty e-mail.

Comment: First make sure that the clipboard contains text

Comment: @Pikoh
Yes it does. I have just tried again. I have used notepad to write some text and then copied it using ctrl + c. Clipboard is not empty.

Comment: Check if you have access to the system Clipboard. (UIPermission) UIPermissionClipboard.AllClipboard

Comment: You need to be in an STA thread. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string

Comment: @ThomasWoelfer 

`[STAThread]` solved the problem.
Thank you all for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

In console app, clipboard is accessible in certain thread states, specifically STA.

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies) for explanation.

So, write a static method like this:

```
static string GetClipboardText()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    Thread staThread = new Thread(x =>
    {
        try
        {
            result = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }
    });
    staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    staThread.Start();
    staThread.Join();
    return result;
}
```

and use it in your main method

```
oMail.TextBody = GetClipboardText();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However what I have done was leaving code as it was with no changes, but I have just added `[STAThread]`above `static void Main(string[] server)`. Works for me. Thank you