# Get the data copied after Ctrl+ C operation to a variable

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys

I have some data in notepad and have performed Sendkeys("Ctrl+C") using keyboard library.I want to get the copied data to a variable in C# code.

How to get the data to variable programmatically.

I tried clipboard.GetText() API and it is giving empty string.

Comment: Can you manually paste elsewhere after doing the `SendKeys` call?  IE have you verified that your copy actually works in the first place?

Comment: Show your attempt to use `clipboard.GetText()`

Comment: Are you sure you've successfully copied the data to clipboard? What happens when you try to use ctrl + v?

Comment: You sent Ctrl-C, did you first send Ctrl-A?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipboard.GetText returns null (empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your could get any data using Clipboard.GetDataObject().

See the example at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject(v=vs.110).aspx)